# Why does JavaScript convert parseInt(0000000101126) to 33366 instead of 101126?

Tags: javascript

Why does JavaScript convert parseInt(0000000101126) to 33366 instead of 101126?

```
var example = parseInt(0000000101126);
console.log(example); //33366
```

Comment: @MarkWalters That also prints 33366

Comment: @Mark The *literal* `0000000000101126` is already interpreted as octal before it even hits `parseInt`.

Comment: Don't pass the value as a Literal to the `parseInt()`, instead pass it as a string : `parseInt('0101126', 10);` http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/VrYL4/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript assumes the following:

•If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
•If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is deprecated
•If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your value in quotes it will give you proper output:

Instead of:

```
var example = parseInt(0000000101126);
```

Try

```
var example = parseInt("0000000101126");
```

Comment: I can't explicitly write parseInt("0000000101126") because 0000000101126 is coming from one row out of thousands being processed in a loop. Even if I put 0000000101126 into a variable first and convert it to string using example.toString() it still returns 33366

Comment: @Jonathan You could post another question with the code that produces parseInt(010126) signaling the problem (that the number is interpreted as octal) and you can get a solution. Your current question seems to be limited to finding out why this correct behavior is happening, not how to get a solution to your problem.

Comment: @DownVoter reason for downvoting will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if `parseInt` value starts from `0` javascript engine evaluate it like `octal` value.
But ECMAScript 5 [removes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#ECMAScript_5_removes_octal_interpretation) octal interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it's being converted to [Octal](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp).

> The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.
>
> The radix parameter is used to specify which numeral system to be
>   used, for example, a radix of 16 (hexadecimal) indicates that the
>   number in the string should be parsed from a hexadecimal number to a
>   decimal number.
>   If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> ```
> - If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
> - If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is deprecated
> - If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that it's not `parseInt` which interprets your number as octal, but the JS interpreter.

[This section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) of ECMAScript describes how numbers in source code are interpreted by the JS interpreter. [This one](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1)  describes the grammar for octal numbers.

Some overzelousness of eliminating the ambiguity of octal literals results in interesting scenarios :

**(Chrome 32)**

```
01.0 // SyntaxError: Unexpected number
01.9 // SyntaxError: Unexpected number
09.9 // 9.9

(function(){"use strict"; 01;})() // SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
(function(){"use strict"; 01.0;})() // SyntaxError: Unexpected number
(function(){"use strict"; console.log(09.9);})() // 9.9
```

**Firefox 26**

```
01.0 // SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
09.0 // SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
09.9 // 9.9

(function(){"use strict"; 01;})() // SyntaxError: octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated
(function(){"use strict"; 01.0;})() // SyntaxError: octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated
(function(){"use strict"; 09.9;})() // SyntaxError: octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated
```

Answer (score 0):

In C type languages integer can be represented in multiple ways:

- As ocatl number by putting 0 in front 0101126
- As decimal by putting
  nothing in fron 101126
- As hexadecimal number by putting 0x in front
  0x101126

Each of these parseInt will convert to decimal base, so your octal base number is converted to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the number into "number"! 
The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.
Like this:

```
var example = parseInt("0000000101126");
console.log(example);
```